# How should I update a div whenever new data is POSTed to my Flask SQLAlchemy application?

Tags: python, jquery, flask

I am making a chat application in Flask for practice, and I need the HTML div on the chat page to automatically retrieve new chat messages without simply refreshing the whole page.

From what I have found, it is recommended to frequently read a JSON file created server-side and use AJAX and JQUERY to update the div's text. However, my code does not appear to be making any GET requests automatically. In `chat.html`:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
  var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(
    function()
    {
        $.getJSON(
            $SCRIPT_ROOT+'/_chat_update',
            {
                ChatId: $({{ chatid }}).val()
            },
            function(data)
            {
                $("#chat-main").text(data.updated);
            });

    },
    500);
</script>
<div id="chat-main">
{% for line in chatLines %}
<p>{{ line.sent_by }}: {{ line.line_text }}</p>
{% else %}
<em>there's nothing here...</em>
{% endfor %}
</div>
...
```

And server side

```
@app.route('/c/<chatid>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def chat(chatid):
    c = chatid
    thisChat = Chat.query.get(chatid)
    thisUser = User.query.filter_by(user_email=session['signed-in-user']).first()
    chatLines = Line.query.filter_by(chat_line=thisChat).all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newLine = Line(published_date=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), chat_line=thisChat, line_author=thisUser, line_text=request.form['newline-input'])
        db.session.add(newLine)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('chat', chatid=c))
    return render_template('chat.html', chatLines=chatLines, chatid=c)

@app.route('/_chat_update')
def chat_update():
    ChatId = request.args.get('ChatId', 0, type=int)
    thisChat = Chat.query.get(ChatId)
    newChatLines=Line.query.filter_by(chat_line=thisChat).all()
    return jsonify(updated=newChatLines)
```

What I was anticipating would happen is, every 500 milliseconds, the JSON at `/_chat_update` would be grabbed and the HTML div would update with the results – in hind site this should only happen if the JSON is different from the current version, but that's for another time. For now, I am wondering if 1. I am on the right track and where I may have gone wrong here, or 2. if there is a better way to get such database additions live. Many thanks for your help.

EDIT

There is a bug that appears twice a second, so it must be related to the call I am trying to make above. It is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined  jquery.min.js:1
st.fn.extend.val                                                   jquery.min.js:1
(anonymous function)
```

Comment: Try to inspect your JavaScript code using browser dev tools (Firebug if you're using Firefox), maybe there's a bug somewhere.

Comment: @AudriusKažukauskas Thanks for the tip – there is an error appearing twice a second, so it must be related to the code above. ``Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined          jquery.min.js:1
st.fn.extend.val          jquery.min.js:1
(anonymous function)``

Comment: Try using unminified version of jQuery, the error message should be more comprehensible then, although I think the problems lies in this line: `ChatId: $({{ chatid }}).val()`.

Comment: It probably needs quotes around `{{ chatid }}`: `ChatId: $('{{ chatid }}').val()`. Otherwise the value of `chatid` is treated as a name in JS code.

Comment: @AudriusKažukauskas Thank you, the quotes did the trick. Now the call is made, but the argument is not being passed properly. However, if I cannot figure this out after rereading the relevant docs I will post a new question. Many thanks